# How to change Javascript audio object src?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, media

I'm creating a custom HTML5 audio player. I have the following snippet in my script.

```
var curAudio = new Audio('Audio.mp3');
$("#play").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    curAudio.play();
});
$("#next").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [UPDATE curAudio SRC here]
    curAudio.play();
});
```

This snippet is highly simplified and isn't very practical but good enough for my question which is, How do I update the src of the audio object dynamically? If I use

```
var curAudio = $("#audio");
```

I can easily change the src using

```
curAudio.attr("src", "newaudio.mp3");
```

But how do I do it with the former method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a different source with the Element's [`src` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Properties):

```
curAudio.src = 'http://.../newaudio.mp3';
```

This is what [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) accomplishes for jQuery collections:

```
$("#audio").prop('src', 'http://.../newaudio.mp3');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Do

    var curAudio = new Audio("audio.mp3");

and
    var curAudio = $("#audiotag");

behave the same way? Can they be manipulated the same way like, for example, by using

    curAudio.attr("src", "newaudio.mp3");

?

Comment: @DavidHeisnam Yes and no. Setting an attribute with either will behave the same, but each have their own method for doing that. jQuery collections have [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) whereas `Element`s have [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute). Though, generally, you'll want to manipulate [properties rather than attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: You've been of great help. Thanks a lot Jonathan Lonowski!